# Отобразить контент по центру страницы

Tags: html

Необходимо, чтобы весь контент отображался по центру страницы. Пытаюсь, не могу добиться:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>ТЕСТ</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                <main class="content">
                    <b> 
                    <span class="term">HTML</span>
                    </b>
                (от англ. 
                <i>
                <span class="hint">HyperText Markup Language</span>
                </i>
                 — «язык гипертекстовой разметки») -  стандартизированный язык разметки документов во 
                <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Всемирная_паутина">Всемирной паутине
                </a>
                . Большинство веб-страниц содержат описание разметки на языке HTML (или XHTML). Язык HTML интерпретируется браузерами; полученный в результате интерпретации форматированный текст отображается на экране монитора компьютера или мобильного устройства.
            </main>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте свой `css` и после body явно тег p лишний

Answer (score 1):

размер width блока body задавайте какой вам нужен.

```css
    body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>ТЕСТ</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                <main class="content">
                    <b> 
                    <span class="term">HTML</span>
                    </b>
                (от англ. 
                <i>
                <span class="hint">HyperText Markup Language</span>
                </i>
                 — «язык гипертекстовой разметки») -  стандартизированный язык разметки документов во 
                <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Всемирная_паутина">Всемирной паутине
                </a>
                . Большинство веб-страниц содержат описание разметки на языке HTML (или XHTML). Язык HTML интерпретируется браузерами; полученный в результате интерпретации форматированный текст отображается на экране монитора компьютера или мобильного устройства.
            </main>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: зачем задавать размер body, если есть main?

Comment: Там намеки на появление контента за пределами main (незакрытый тег p), а автор просил именно весь контент сделать по центру. Поэтому стили применены к body.

Comment: там условие, не пользоваться CSS, только HTML

Comment: а весь список условий огласить сразу можно?